# Using R openxlsx and mapply packages to output all excel worksheets to a list of dataframes resulting an error

Tags: r, excel, sapply, mapply, openxlsx

I'm trying create a list of dataframes from an excel file with multiple tabs using mapply. The following code works fine, but only when referring directly to the file path (f).

```r
f <- workbook file path
mapply(read.xlsx, xlsxFile = f, sheet = Tab_Names, startRow = first_row, 
       colNames = has_headers, sep.names = " ")
```

However, I want to load the workbook first so I can normalize the sheet names. The following code would throw an error.

```r
wb <- loadWorkbook(f)
mapply(read.xlsx, xlsxFile = wb, sheet = Tab_Names, startRow = first_row, 
       colNames = has_headers, sep.names = " ")
# Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
```

The only change I'm making to the mapply is the xlsxFile value, where before I was referring to a file on the drive and now I'm referring to the workbook object I just created. Anybody knows why the this doesn't work?